# How to do the next button action?

Tags: android, textview, radio-button

I'm facing a problem in Next button while displaying the next question.

In my first time set text I'm getting the correct question and matched four option answers. What I needed is.

I have a Next button for displaying the next question and answers. When I click on next button I can get the next four options for next question. But I can't get next question after four times I click on next it shows next question, but answers are correct.

What I'm doing wrong? what I'm missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

> ```
>     protected String doInBackground(String... Args) {
> List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>     System.out.println("cool");
> params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tid", tid));
> json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesurl, "GET", params);
> System.out.println("ques value got");
> Log.d("All Groups: ", json.toString());
>     System.out.println("question");
> try {
> int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
> System.out.println("Success");
> if (success == 1) {
> System.out.println("Success");
> groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
> System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
> for (int i = 0; i < groups.length();i++) {
> JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
>       String question = c.getString(TAG_QUES);
>   System.out.println("Checking ::"+question);
> ques1.add(question);
> String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSW);
> System.out.println("Checking ::"+answer);
> answ1.add(answer);
>        }
>     } else {
>         showAlert();
>     }
> } catch (JSONException e) {
>     System.out.println("Error "+e.toString());
> }
> return null;
>      }  
>      protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>      pDialog.dismiss();
>      ques1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(ques1));
>         //  j=0;
>         TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
>         txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));                      // here im getting the question
>                                                  //   and answers in radiobutton text
>         answ1=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(answ1));
>         btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get(0));
>         btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get(1));
>         btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get(2));
>         btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get(3));
>         btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
>                 RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
>                // Toast.makeText(Question.this, "" + radioButton.getText(), 2000).show(); 
>                 TextView txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rdtxt); 
>                 txtRadio.setText("" + radioButton.getText());
>             }
> });
>     Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxt_btn);
>     nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
>       public void onClick(View v){  
>       j++;
>     TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
>     txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));              // here im not getting the next question
>                                             //   but i can get the next four options in              
>                                             //    radiobutton text
>     k++;
>     btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+0));
>     btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+1));
>     btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+2));
>     btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+3));
>      }
>    });
>     Button previousbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prv_btn);
> previousbtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
> public void onClick(View v){
> j--;
> TextView txtque = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.que_txt); 
> txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));              // here also im not getting the perivous question
>                                         //     but i cant get perivous four options in 
>                                        //      radiobutton text
> k--;
> btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+0));
> btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+1));
> btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+2));
> btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+3));
>   }
> });
>   }
> ```

Comment: Please any one help me..Why im not getting the next question..What im doing wrong?

Comment: @peter o please help me how can i get next question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you are trying to manage question and its options on `next/previous buttons click`.

I achieved in my one of app same as you want:

Step1@ take one `int count=0` define globally.

Step2@ when activity is called initially first question will be display with options.

`setValues(count);` // here I am setting question and options to textview inside setValues named method.

Step3@ `onClick of NextButton` check condition something like below:

```
if (count == question.size() - 1) {
    finish();
    break;
} 

else {
count++;
setValues(count);
   }
```

Step4@ `onClick of PreviousButton` check condition something like below:

```
if (count <= 0) {
Toast.makeText(OnPurposeUPSQuesAcitivty.this, "First Record",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
} else {
count--;
setValues(count);
}
```

Your `setValue` method something look like below:

```
public void setValues( int j) {
txtque.setText(ques1.get(j));            

btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get(j);
btn_practice2.setText(answ1.get(j);
btn_practice3.setText(answ1.get(j);
btn_practice4.setText(answ1.get(j);
}
```

...........

Last Point@ After review your code, I don't came across that how you are setting values to options.

this

> btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get((k*4)+0));

Will you explain above line of code, will update my answer, else you can use my solution as I mention above steps wise.

Comment: ok i try...and say btn_practice1.setText(answ1.get(k*4)+0);   Its means in my answ1 ArrayList it contains 16 options for 4 question each 4 options so when increment i should display next four option so i used above line code for next four options....

Comment: I tried...i didnt get next question..Can you edit your idea in my code itself..please help me im new to android..What im doing wrong i dont know..

Comment: @God'sGrace but why you are getting position like `(k*4)+0);` this?

Comment: First time it displays 0 to 3 elements next when increment "k" becomes 1, so now k=1. but i need 4 to 7. so i done (1*4)+0); so now it displays 4th element...can you understand...

Comment: Only problem is im not getting next question..After i click four times its displays next question...but answers are coming correct..please help me..plz implement your idea in my code, edit and say plz..really i dont know where im getting wrong...

Comment: I tried again i click four times only its showing next question.. same as in perivous also..but answers are coming correct...in both next and perivous...

Comment: vote up my question means u given vote down...change and vote...frnd

Comment: @God'sGrace I didnt given, neither I upvote nor downvoted.BTW! why you need to up your question? Its not a cross agreement, that you upvoted so I also upvote, if I find your question indeed need deserve up then sure I will, but you can't request/force.