# Android : Next/Previous data details from listview items

Tags: android, listview, button

i wanna show the details data from listviews android, i did it...
but the problem is, i don't know how to **make a function to show the next/previous detail data** by clicking the next/previous button based on listview data.

this is [my listview data layout](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57465028/Listview.png)

and this is [my next/previous layout](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57465028/next-previous.png)  for details data

please someone, tell me how to do this (sample code, tutorial, link)

thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Damn it! Play with your array-list data of listview, pass appropriate `position` to next activity and while press next `call next data from array-list`, same while pressing previous `call previous data` from array list, this way you can achieve your goal!

I answered one of similar question hope it will help you.

[stackverflow question:How to do next button action?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14641493/646806)

Comment: hi @Robinhood....i'm still confused about next/previous details data listview....please check [my related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376995/getting-next-and-previous-detail-data-from-listview) 
hope you can help my problem...:)
Thank

Answer (score 0):

1. By using get and set method
   my making a function in different class where activity name is stored.
   You can set every prev or next activity and call it by get method.
2. By calling intent.

Eg:

```
 `    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent_start1();
                finish();
            }

            private void Intent_start1() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i2 = new Intent();
                i2.setClass([Your Current Class].this,[Class where you wish to move].class);
                startActivity(i2);
            }
        }); `
```

Dont call finish() method

I like to use intent :)

Comment: everytime have to call intent, if once it called and now when pressing next, have to call intent again?

Comment: If in same class, You can always call intent again. Even getset method works well.

Comment: seem you not understand the OP question properly. "Once the intent call and next activity start and on next activity there is next button when it click so next data should be display same in the case of previous button but it will display previous data"

Comment: ya..u r right.. for that getset method function should be used..rit?? @Robinhood

Comment: Thank b4 for the answer Mr.Shachi, but i think Mr.Robinhood's answer more closely to what i'm looking for...:)