# pass string from fragment main activity to fragments activity in viewpager

Tags: android, string, android-fragments, fragment

i wanna pass a string to all fragment(child) from fragment activity (main), may be this picture can explain what exactly what i want to do

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57465028/SC20140205-163325.png

so, from above picture...i wanna pass a string from edittext by press a button to all activity in viewpager....how could i do that?

i tried to follow this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/12739968/2003393 but it can't solved my problem..

please help me...i'm stuck

thank in advance.

here is my code from fragment activity (MainActivity)

public class Swipe_Menu extends FragmentActivity {

```
//String KeyWord;


//private static final String KEYWORD = "keyword";

private ViewPager _mViewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter _adapter;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.swipe_menu_image);


    Button Back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.account);
    ImageButton Search = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.search);
    EditText Keyword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.keyword);

    final String KeyWord = Keyword.getText().toString(); 


    /**
     * Back button click event
     * */
    Back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            finish();
        }
    });



    setUpView();
    setTab();
}

protected void sendValueToFragments(String value) {
    // it has to be the same name as in the fragment
    Intent intent = new Intent("my_package.action.UI_UPDATE");
    intent.putExtra("UI_KEY", KeyWord  );
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

and here is my fragment (Child Activity)

```
public class Store_Swipe extends Fragment {

public static final String ACTION_INTENT = "my_package.action.UI_UPDATE";

String KeyWord;
private TextView kata_keyword;

protected BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(ACTION_INTENT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String value = intent.getStringExtra("UI_KEY");
            updateUIOnReceiverValue(value);
        }
    }
};

private void updateUIOnReceiverValue(String value) {
    // you probably want this:
    KeyWord = value;
}

public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    Store_Swipe f = new Store_Swipe();
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_INTENT);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /*Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    KeyWord = bundle.getString("keyword");*/
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_swipe, container, false);
    init(view);

    return view;

}

void init(View view) {
    kata_keyword = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.keyword);
    //ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_error);
    kata_keyword.setText(KeyWord);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have access directly to your fragments that reside in `ViewPager` so you can't reference them directly.

What I am doing in these cases is send a broadcast message from Activity to Fragments. For this reason register a `BroadcatReceiver` in the fragment (either in `onCreate` or `onCreateView` - your decision)m, set a custom action for that receiver (ex. `"my_package.actions.internal.BROADCAST_ACTION"`), don't forget to unregister the receiver from complementary method.

When you want to send a message from activity, create an intent with above mentioned action, add the string in intent extra and send the broadcast.

In your receiver's `onReceive` method (within the fragment), get the String from intent paramter and there you have the string.

Makes sense?

**EDIT**: To provide some code, below are the changes that I would make for fragment:

```
public class Store_Swipe extends Fragment {

    public static final String ACTION_INTENT = "my_package.action.UI_UPDATE";

    protected BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(ACTION_INTENT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                String value = intent.getStringExtra("UI_KEY");
                updateUIOnReceiverValue(value);
            }
        }
    };

    private void updateUIOnReceiverValue(String value) {
        // you probably want this:
        kata_keyword.setText(value);
    }

    String KeyWord;
    private TextView kata_keyword;

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        Store_Swipe f = new Store_Swipe();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_INTENT);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        KeyWord = bundle.getString("keyword");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_swipe, container, false);
        init(view);

        return view;

    }

    void init(View view) {
        kata_keyword = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.keyword);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_error);
        kata_keyword.setText(KeyWord);
    }
}
```

And this code I would have from activity, the parameter is the value from EditText:

```
protected void sendValueToFragments(String value) {
    // it has to be the same name as in the fragment
    Intent intent = new Intent("my_package.action.UI_UPDATE");
    intent.putExtra("UI_KEY", value);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

You would call this from the click listener that you would set in `onCreate`:

```
findViewById(R.id.button_id).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String valueThatYouWantToSend = null; /// just the value
        sendValueToFragments(valueThatYouWantToSend);       
    }
});
```

Comment: thank anyway, @gunar
but, i'm a newbie in android...:D
can you show me some code, where i have to put **BroadcatReceiver** in onCreate or OnCreateView?

Comment: how about AndroidManifest file? should i configure it for Broadcastreceiver?

Comment: you don't need to; because you're sending message from within the app to its components.

Comment: i've edit my code like your method, but my child activity (Store_Swipe ) can't receive string from main acitivty (Swipe_Menu)...
what's wrong?..please check my edited code

Comment: Did you send the broadcast message from activity? The intent has the same action?

Comment: one more, is it need a trigger like (pressing a button) to send string   in edittext?

Comment: of course ... you need to call `sendValueToFragments` from your button click or on another action that you choose.

Comment: i've edit your answer code....do you mean like that?
to call **sendValueToFragments** in button click listener

Comment: I still don't see who's calling `sendValueToFragments(String value)`

Comment: i'm sorry for this misunderstand, what i want to do is, how to call **protected void sendValueToFragments(String value)** from **OnClickListener**

Comment: Great..but how i put the parameter(value) to **onCreateView** in Store_Swipe activtiy...you just put it on **updateUIOnReceiverValue**

Comment: from your post `i wanna pass a string from edittext` ... then `valueThatYouWantToSend` is your edittext `getText().toString()`. Makes sense? Also don't forget to upvote an answer if that is useful

Comment: hi gunar....can you help me to solve [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21678418/2003393)

Answer (score 0):

// I think this solution will solved your issue

```
 // In Main activity put your code -----------------------------------
 public void onPageSelected(int position)
    {

        System.out.println("nilesh");   

        PageOneFragment f = new PageOneFragment();
    f.getText();

    PageTwoFragment ff = new PageTwoFragment();
    ff.setText();

    }

  //in General Class ------------------------------------------------
   public class General 
  {
     public static String name="";
  }

  // first Fragment ---------------------------------------------
   public void getText()
  {
    General.name = edittext.getText().toString();
  }

  // second Fragment ----------------------------------------------
   public void setText()
   {
      System.out.println("name**" + General.name);
      tv.setText(General.name);
  }
```

Comment: thank anyway, but i'm trying to do **BroadcastReceiver** method like my edited code...