# android add setOnClickListener function in view pager fragment

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, sliding

i have a fragment activity which has 4 child fragments ....
i've success to add swipe function (sliding), but i don't know how to add setOnClickListener function when i click tab menu, i want my app can provide 2 ways to access an activity (sliding page and click tab menu)....how can i do that?

thank in advance

this is my MainActivity

```
public class ViewPagerStyle1Activity extends FragmentActivity {
    private ViewPager _mViewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter _adapter;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setUpView();
        setTab();
    }
    private void setUpView(){       
     _mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
     _adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),getSupportFragmentManager());
     _mViewPager.setAdapter(_adapter);
     _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
    private void setTab(){
            _mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {}
                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}
                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            switch(position){
                            case 0:
                                findViewById(R.id.first_tab).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                findViewById(R.id.second_tab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                findViewById(R.id.first_tab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                findViewById(R.id.second_tab).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    });

    }
}
```

and this is my ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context _context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);  
        _context=context;

        }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = new Fragment();
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            f=LayoutOne.newInstance(_context);  
            break;
        case 1:
            f=LayoutTwo.newInstance(_context);  
            break;
        }
        return f;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

Comment: [This][1] should answer your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337514/android-tabwidget-detect-click-on-current-tab?tab=active#tab-top

Comment: @Shaho: thank anyway, i don't use **TabHost** i use **ViewPagerAdapter**...how could i use **TabHost** in my code?

Comment: Follow this developer article - [Effective navigation, Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)