# LocalBroadcastManager for multiple intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm working in an app where I have just implemented the ViewPager. I was first working with tabs but when I made the change to ViewPager I started having an issue with the data transfer from Activity to fragments.

I finally found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573810/pass-string-from-fragment-main-activity-to-fragments-activity-in-viewpager?rq=1) where this issue was explained and where recomends to use LocalBroadcastManager to send data from Activity to Frament when using ViewPager. I have implemented this code and works fine:

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public static final String ACTION_INTENT = "fragment1.action.BOX_UPDATE";

    /*Register the receiver*/
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_INTENT);
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(ActivityDataReceiver, filter);
    }

    /*Broadcast Receiver*/
    protected BroadcastReceiver ActivityDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(ACTION_INTENT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                String text = intent.getStringExtra("TEXT");
                witeOnBox(text);
            }
        }
    };

    /*Method which changes the text with the icoming value*/
    public void witeOnBox(String text) {
        tv_log.setText(text);

    }

    /*Unregister receiver*/
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(ActivityDataReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Now, in MainActivity I send the data to the fragment this way:

```
protected void sendValueToFragment1(String text) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("fragment1.action.BOX_UPDATE");
    intent.putExtra("TEXT", text);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Now I need to send other data from MainActivity to the same Fragment1, and my question is, how do I manage in the fragment the incoming of another intent?

Do I have to create another BroadcastReceiver to manage a new Intent, or can I manage a new intent in the same BroadcastRecevier? I see that I can check using an `if` inside the onReceive() method of the BroadcastReceiver for the incoming intent filter, but If I declare two diferent intent filters in the same fragment, how do I asign them to the BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally solved adding an Action to the previously defined IntentFilter:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_INTENT);
    filter.addAction(ACTION_INTENT2);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(ActivityDataReceiver, filter);
}
```

Then in the BroadcastReceiver I manage the incoming actions:

```
protected BroadcastReceiver ActivityDataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(ACTION_INTENT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //Do
        }
        if(ACTION_INTENT2.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //DO
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Much better ways than using broadcast receiver,

```
  Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + mPager.getCurrentItem());
            if(frag!=null && mPager.getCurrentItem()==1){
                ((Fragment1) frag).setText(text);
            }
```

If you navigate to the Fragment after this has been called you can have it get the variables from the Activity using getActivity();

Comment: Thats the way I was doing it before implementing the LocalBroadcastManager, and it wasn't working. As gunar says in the linked post `You don't have access directly to your fragments that reside in ViewPager so you can't reference them directly.`

Comment: Ok I didn't see that bit. With regards your question then you should use the same broadcast receiver you should just change the TAG. Then checking for the TAG in the Fragment for null to call different methods.